# How to disable bottom navigation bar until fragment loads?

Tags: android

I created `BottomNavigationBar` and it is working fine with every `fragment`. Now my problem is when I click for first `fragment` in `BottomNavigationBar` it is taking time to load the data I agree upon it because there is a ton of data to get, but when a user clicks on another `fragment` while the first `fragment` is still loading in the background the server get's disconnected and I am getting `volley` `response` as `ResponseTimedOut` and that's the end of application. So, how to disable user interaction with `BottomNavigationBar` until the first `fragment` is loaded?

Comment: Disable the buttons when the user has clicked one and re-enable it at the end of OnCreate within the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

```
   navigationBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(null);
```

Will disable the item selection callbacks.

Use `navigationBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);` to enable them back on.

Comment: Where should I place this code in fragment oncreate or where navigationbar is created?

Comment: Right after you create the navigation bar disable it. Then, when you get what you need from the internet, enable it